# Dot(.) not converted to unicode: Dataset.WriteXML C#

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, dataset, writexml

I am writing a DataSet into an XML file using:

```
DataSet.WriteXml(XMLWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

`XMLWriter` encoding is set with `Encoding.UTF8`.

All works fine with my code, except the dot (`'.'`) character. `WriteXml` converts special characters into Unicode HEX, for example, space (`' '`) as `x0020` and underscore (`'_'`) as `x005F`. However, dot (`'.'`) is stored as-is.

**How to make sure that dot (`'.'`) is stored as `x2024` in the XML file generated using `DataSet.WriteXML`?**

Comment: Presumably you're talking about encoding of characters in *element names*.  The `.` character is included as-is in the name because it's a valid character to include in an element name.  From the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-NameChar): `NameChar    ::=    Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | CombiningChar | Extender`.  See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename(v=vs.110).aspx) for `XmlConvert.EncodeName()` for more about how arbitrary strings get encoded as element names.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I am specifically inquiring about DataSet.WriteXML functionality, because I am not creating XML file manually. Rather, I create a DataSet and calls its WriteXML method to generate the XML file. In this scenario, if someone has come across a solution then it will be helpful for me

Comment: "*is stored as x2024*" - that is done for Unicode codepoint [U+2024 ONE DOT LEADER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2024/index.htm), which is a very different character than [U+002E FULL STOP](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002e/index.htm) (aka the ASCII "period"). U+002E does not need to be hex encoded.